# How to average across several rows, for many columns, using data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset where pairs of rows can have the same value on variable X1. I would like to average these paired rows' values in columns 2:40, into a new single row for each. Is there an easy way to do this?

If it were just one column I was averaging I think I could do this:

```
d[, X2 := X2, by = X1]
```

But this becomes very tedious for multiple columns. Is there a way to do this in data.table without having to type out `X := X` for each column?

Edit:

Here is a reproducible example. I would essentially like to end up with ten rows, one for each value of "cat". These rows would contain averages of x1, x2 and x3, for that level of "cat".

```
cat <- rep(1:10, times = 2)
x1 <- rnorm(20)
x2 <- rnorm(20)
x3 <- rnorm(20)

dat <- cbind(cat, x1, x2, x3)

dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
```

Comment: maybe something like `d[, mX := rowMeans(.SD), X1, .SDcols=X2:X40]`

Comment: Do you just want unique rows then? Maybe `unique(d, by=names(d))`  where you can specifically select your `by=` columns if you don't want to use all?

Comment: @RonakShah Have now added sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution will suit, as you haven't provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but perhaps something like this?

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(X1 = rep(1:50, each = 2),
                 X2 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X3 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X4 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X5 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X6 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X7 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X8 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X9 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X10 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50)
                 )
setDT(df)
head(df)
#>    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 2:  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
#> 3:  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 4:  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
#> 5:  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 6:  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2

df2 <- df[ ,lapply(.SD, mean), by = X1, .SDcols = X2:X10]
head(df2)
#>    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
#> 1:  1 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 2:  2 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 3:  3 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 4:  4 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 5:  5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 6:  6 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

--

Or maybe this?

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(X1 = 1:100,
                 X2 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X3 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X4 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X5 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X6 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X7 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X8 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X9 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50),
                 X10 = rep(x = 1:2, times = 50)
                 )
setDT(df)
head(df)
#>    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#> 1:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 2:  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
#> 3:  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 4:  4  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
#> 5:  5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 6:  6  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2

df2 <- df[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), X1-0:1]
head(df2)
#>    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
#> 1:  1 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 2:  3 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 3:  5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 4:  7 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 5:  9 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
#> 6: 11 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! For posterity, I added example data in an edit. Thanks again!